# Syntax Error: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I suspect that I have a missing bracket but I can't find one if there is

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#additional_info_submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "advice_response.php",
            //contentType: "text/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                alert('yay');
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried commenting out sections to narrow it down to specific parts of the code?

Comment: There don't appear to be any `SyntaxError`s within the snippet. Have you checked that the response from `advice_response.php` is [valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/)?

Comment: no, thats the full code

Comment: @Strelok, thanks, will do, but even with all of that removed and only the alert left in place I still get the error

Comment: @tatty27 Following on from my previous comment, can you post the *minimum* file that still shows the problem?

Comment: does it require a trigger create call

Comment: @AdrianWragg I've cut it down to the bare minimum and it still does the same thing

Comment: do your $('#form').serialize outside the ajax call and see what happens; also, use a program like Fiddler2 to post a blank request to that php page and see what it says.

Comment: ok, it seems that the issue is the JSON, as soon as I remove that and just send it as a serialised form I get somewhere

Comment: ok, thanks to everyone for their help, by removing the json the form is submitting just fine and updating the database etc so I may as well just leave it at that and check out the JSON to see where it went wrong in the morning

Comment: @tatty27 Are you able to post a fully non-working (!) sample of this somewhere, so others can attempt to see the problem in a "live" environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json_encode on the advice_response.php was missing a semi colon at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for "PUT" method but I'm using Web Api server side so I had to change in my Web Api Controller Put Method from this :

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

to this:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, MyUpdatedObject);
```